# regular expression for getting the content between [ ] in string in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to output the strings between [].
For example I need this-echo, nobody to be displayed.
But I am get this as result: [this-echo] Hello Everybody [nobody].

```
$txt = 'Hello World [this-echo] Hello Everybody [nobody]';
$regExp = '/\[([^)]+)\]/';
$match = preg_match("/\[(.*)\]/s", $txt, $output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $txt, $out);
print_r($out[1]);
```

get

```
Array ( [0] => this-echo [1] => nobody )
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of excluding the closing square bracket, you have excluded the closing round bracket in your character class: `[^)]` That is why the pattern doesn't stop at the first closing square bracket and reach the last of the string.

You only need to replace it with `[^]]` and to use `preg_match_all` to get several results.